# Two particles moving in a circle due to mutual gravity - slight change

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames

Situation given:

Two diametrically-opposite particles move on a circle under the action of their mutual gravitational attraction.

[image]

 Here, I can calculate the speed of each particle by equating  centripetal force with mutual gravitational force.

My question is- what if the masses aren't diametrically opposite? Will they

(a) move with a constant velocity around the same circle, with a fixed distance between them?

(b) close in on the same circle and collide?

(c) form a new circle with the line segment connecting them as the diameter and mid-point of the line segment as the centre of the new circle?

[image]

note that i did not want the new circle in my diagram to pass through the circle's centre.

 Here's the actual question, printed in a book of mine:
[image]

Comment: The two particles cannot move in the way you describe because the centre of mass of the system would be moving. Conservation of momentum requires the centre of mass to remain stationary.

Comment: do you mean the 'situation given'- situation is not possible?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: on the other hand if you mean, the second situation, then  centre of mass remains stationary in all ( a,b and c) possibilities. But I am not sure which one is accurate.

Comment: @JohnRennie The question has been printed in a book of mine. Should I add a picture to my question here to make the situation easy to understand?

Comment: You could add the picture if you think it would help

Comment: What do you mean by "not diametrically opposed"?   That phrase implies that there is no diameter ... they are not moving in respective circles, which is indeed possible.   And what's the difference between (a) and (c).  They look the same to me.   I think you need to think about what it is that you really want to know, and clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no external forces, the particles must move in such a way that their centre of mass remains stationary. (The centre of mass could also move with constant velocity, but I shall assume we are observing from a frame in which it is stationary.) The centre of mass is always at the midpoint between the particle. So they cannot be in the situation shown in your 2nd diagram, moving on the solid circle (option a), because the centre of mass would then be moving around in a circle of its own, without any external force to cause this motion.

If the particles were somehow arranged as in the 2nd diagram, having velocities with the same magnitude but directed at right angles, they would not move in either the solid circle or the dashed circle. They would not move in a circle at all : they would move in an ellipse.

In order to move in a circle the velocities must be pointing in opposite directions (1st diagram). The magnitude of the velocities $v_0$ required for circular motion is precisely determined by the gravitational force and the distance between them, as you found by solving the book problem. If the particle velocities are opposite but greater or less than $v_0$, or if the velocities are not opposite (eg at right angles, as in the 2nd diagram), then the particles will move in an ellipse instead of a circle. (*Note:* if the particle velocities are large enough they could also fly apart.)

So in the situation illustrated in the 2nd diagram none of options (a), (b) or (c) would happen.